# Events release_service_addr and release_takeover_addr in PowerHA

Tags: event-handling, aix

I was trying to configure some post-event-script in [PowerHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_High_Availability_Cluster_MultiprocessingX) (halevel: 7.2.4 SP2, AIX 7200-05-03-2148) in a simple two-node active-standby cluster with a single resource group. The script was only executed when moving the resource group from the a- to the b-node, not the other way round.

With testing I found out that the cluster executes the event *release_service_addr* when moving from a-node to b-node (primary to secondary node), but it executes *release_takeover_addr* instead going in the other direction.

What is the explanation for this rather weird behavior? Or is this a bug in PowerHA?

Comment: I don't know if this behaviour is weird or not, but is it documented?

Comment: @Zsigmond Lőrinczy: not to my knowledge. The closest i came for any documentation about *any* HACMP-events was in the "Tivoli Composite Application Manager for Applications v7.2.0": https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/itcam-app-mgr/7.2.0?topic=SS3JRN_7.2.0/com.ibm.itm.doc/main_log02.htm

Comment: Yes, i have seen that and read the description of both. I still don't understand the difference between the "release_service_addr" event and the "release_takeover_addr" event (hence the "weird" commentary) and i don't understand why one is invoked goin in one and the other going in the other direction when moving the RG back and forth.

Comment: Maybe roles _primary_ and _standby_ are asymetric in their book, that's why the transitions between them aren't symetric either.

Comment: Interesting point, but i don't think this is the case: HACMP "rotating clusters" (HACMP speak for the common setup with one active and one standby node) basically define a list of (identical) nodes which is then ordered alphabetically. "Primary" just means that the host name is first alphabetically, not even that it is in any way the preferred one. The descriptions of both events are identical too.